# django media not loading

Tags: python, django, media, django-urls, django-settings

So using django for the first time and ran into this issue where the media url does not want to load/work so far my urls.py is setup like so

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('',
 (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),)
```

my settings.py like so

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http:/localhost:8000/admin-media/'
```

my html template like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/template.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
```

Whenever I type in http://localhost:8000/media/css/template.css I get

```
AttributeError at /media/css/template.css/

'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'
```

and in my django server log the following

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 283, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 272, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 169, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 218, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return callback(request, **param_dict)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 93, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\defaults.py", line 30, in server_error
    t = loader.get_template(template_name) # You need to create a 500.html template.

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 157, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 138, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name)

    TemplateDoesNotExist: 500.html
```

When I type http://localhost:8000/home/ my page loads but none of my css or javascript is loaded..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Django for the first time, you should be using 1.4. If you're using a lesser version, upgrade before going any farther. Starting a new project on an old version of the framework will bite you later.

So, given Django 1.4. You need the following (and only the following):

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'assets'),
)
```

`PROJECT_ROOT` is just a convenience variable to save repetition; it doesn't have anything to do with Django. The "assets" directory is where you will put all your project-wide static resources. You can name that anything you like, it just can't be the same as `MEDIA_ROOT` or `STATIC_ROOT`.

Also note: `MEDIA_ROOT` is now only for uploads, i.e. files added via `FileField`s and `ImageField`s on your models. `STATIC_ROOT` is only for the output of the `collectstatic` management command, which you'll only use in production; you never actually store anything there yourself.

If you're using `runserver` in development, Django will automatically serve all your static resources for you. *Only if you're using another webserver in development, will you need to add the following to urls.py*:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Finally, in order to serve your `MEDIA_ROOT` directory in development add the following to urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
   )
```

In production, both `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` will be served directly by your webserver, not Django.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

http://redsymbol.net/articles/django-attributeerror-str-object-no-attribute-resolve/

> Say you are working on a Django project, using its development web
>   server, and you get this exception when you try to load a page in the
>   browser:
>
> ```
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve'
> ```
>
> It's because
>   you forgot to type the word "patterns".
>
> Specifically, in some url.py, you typed something like this:
>
> ```
> urlpatterns = ('', (r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template':'a.html'}),
>
> # ... when you should have typed this:
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('', (r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template':'a.html'}),
>
> # ... See the difference?
> ```
>
> In the first one, I'm
>   incorrectly assigning urlpatterns to be a tuple. In the second, I'm
>   correctly using the django.conf.urls.defaults.patterns function.

Comment: this is strange because my urls.py has the following urlpatterns = patterns('', ('^home/$', master_page),                    
                       ('^footer/$'),
                      )

Answer (score -1):

us this code

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': 'media','show_indexes': True}),
    )
```