# Access images on localhost

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

I have a `Django` project where I want to access some images.

I have set the paths in `mySite\settings.py` like so

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My urls are defined like this:

```
from . import views                                                

urlpatterns = [                                                    
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),                     
]

if settings.DEBUG:                                                 
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)                 
    urlpatterns += patterns('',                                    
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,                  
        }),                                                        
   )
```

So the images are located in `mySite/media/subfolder`. Now I want to display my images on my page, the `src` for my `<img>-tag` are like this

```
/media/subfolder/foobar.png
```

So the full path is `http://localhost:8000//media/subfolder/foobar.png` (checked in the web console). However, no pictures are showing up. I also tried other different absolute paths like `http://localhost:8000/subfolder/foobar.png` or `http://localhost:8000/foobar.png`, but no images are shown.

I've read [Django MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517950/django-media-url-and-media-root) and [django media not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915392/django-media-not-loading), but it didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: DEBUG = True in settings, right?

Comment: Does `MEDIA_ROOT` have the value you think it does? You call `dirname` on `__file__` twice, so if `__file__` is *…/mySite/settings.py*, then the result will be the parent of *mySite*. Appending *media* to that won't give you *mySite/media*.

Comment: @ZackTanner Yes, `DEBUG` is set to `True`

Comment: @RobKennedy I just printed out the paths, and I think it shows the correct ones: `BASE_DIR: /Projects/mySite`, `MEDIA_ROOT: /Projects/mySite/media`, `MEDIA_URL: /media/` and `__file__: /Projects/mySite/mySite/settings.py`.

Comment: I see. You have two levels of project directories. I wouldn't expect that, but c'est la vie.

Comment: @RobKennedy Yeah, it's kind of weird, but when you start a new project in Django, it automatically creates that structure.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the mistake.

The problem was that I have put the url setting in the wrong `urls.py`. My `mySite/urls.py` had the following code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^app/', include('app.urls')),
]
```

And in my app I had the above mentioned code. Thus, the path to my `media` folder was wrong. Now I moved

```
if settings.DEBUG:                                                 
    # static files (images, css, javascript, etc.)                 
    urlpatterns += patterns('',                                    
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,                  
        }),                                                        
   )
```

to `mySite/urls.py` and the paths are correct and the images are shown.